# Where is the Json Web Token flag in geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, the-merge, teku

I am running a [teku](https://docs.teku.consensys.net/en/latest/) consensus node for the ETH merge, which requires a [json web token](https://docs.teku.consensys.net/en/22.8.1/HowTo/Prepare-for-The-Merge/#3-configure-the-json-web-token) to be configured using the `ee-jwt-secret-file` configuration option.

To run the two successfully, I need to use the [geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/) (or other execution layer) json web token flag as well to connect the two.

What is the correct option to use on `geth` to make sure the `teku` node can communicate with the `geth` node?

Is it `--authrpc.jwtsecret`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the `--authrpc.jwtsecret` flag

A full geth command ready for the merge might look like the following:

```bash
geth --authrpc.addr localhost --authrpc.port 8551 --authrpc.vhosts localhost --authrpc.jwtsecret /tmp/jwtsecret
```

Note, your `teku` node will need to look for port `8551` if using the command above.